# Model-View-ViewModel: Sync a 50 item ViewModel with an 800 item Server collection?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, mvvm, knockout.js

I am looking for some well accepted pattern or method that keeps a max 50 item ViewModel on the client in sync with an 800 item data table on the server (I'll be using Knockout.js and ASP.NET MVC 3, although this should be irrelevant.)  The items are Entities with multiple properties.  I'll need to add/edit/remove items, loading and unloading ViewModel items as needed, even determining when to load and unload items based on user interaction.

Are there any largely use patterns or methods out there that deal with syncing a large data set with a client side ViewModel, book reference, or web link?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it sounds like HTML5 Local Storage might work for you.  Here's an [overview](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) and an [example application](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage.aspx).